# php curly braces replace values

Tags: php, curly-braces

I never used before curly braces in php

However i'm updating an existant website...

In database i have information such as in

```
YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME}
```

I would like to retrieve the information and show it in appropriate
I want to affect the CH_NAME Variable to a value & same to URL_NAME and in final show full infrmation such :

1-Normal :

```
$beforeStr="YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME}";
$CH_NAME="John";
$URL_NAME="http://xxxx";

echo $beforeStr ; //would like to show : YOUR NAME John http://xxxx
```

Regards

Comment: You should search for templating software, it will do things like this automatically.

Comment: Curly braces don't have any special meaning in strings. They can be used in string **literals**, like `$beforeStr="YOUR NAME {$CH_NAME}";`. But if you're getting the string from a database there's no substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use curly braces, try this. All replaces will be done automatically, just from matched variable names.

```
$CH_NAME = "John";
$URL_NAME = "http://xxxx";
$beforeStr = "YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME}";

preg_match_all('/{(\w+)}/', $beforeStr, $matches);
$afterStr = $beforeStr;
foreach ($matches[0] as $index => $var_name) {
  if (isset(${$matches[1][$index]})) {
    $afterStr = str_replace($var_name, ${$matches[1][$index]}, $afterStr);
  }
}

echo $afterStr;
```

Comment: thanks Max Zuber , even tought it was my first idea to do str replace , i done it but with specificied values in array , you dynamic regex solution is best by far

Answer (score 5):

Only you have to use `str_replace` :

```
$beforeStr="YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME}";

$CH_NAME="John";
$URL_NAME="http://xxxx";
$OTHER = "OTHER";

$beforeStr = str_replace(
array('{CH_NAME}','{URL_NAME}','{OTHER}'),
array($CH_NAME,$URL_NAME,$OTHER),
$beforeStr);

echo $beforeStr ;
```

other way is:

```
$beforeStr = "YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME} - {OTHER} ";

$variables = array(
  'CH_NAME'=>'John',
  'URL_NAME'=>'http://xxxx',
  'OTHER'=>'other'
);
//if var exist then replace
$response = preg_replace_callback('/{(.+?)}/ix',function($match)use($variables){
     return !empty($variables[$match[1]]) ? $variables[$match[1]] : $match[0];
},$beforeStr);

echo $response;
```

Comment: `ix` in this pattern indicates a lack of understanding of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that can help you with that. This one is taken from [Yii::t()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-baseyii#t()-detail) function.

```
function replace_placeholder($message, $params = [])
{
    $placeholders = [];
    foreach ((array) $params as $name => $value) {
        $placeholders['{' . $name . '}'] = $value;
    }
    return ($placeholders === []) ? $message : strtr($message, $placeholders);
}
```

Here is how to use the function,

```
$beforeStr="YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME}";
$values = ['CH_NAME'=>"John",'URL_NAME'=>"http://xxxx"];

echo replace_placeholder($beforeStr,$values);
```

Full example is here

```
<?php
function replace_placeholder($message, $params = [])
{
    $placeholders = [];
    foreach ((array) $params as $name => $value) {
        $placeholders['{' . $name . '}'] = $value;
    }
    return ($placeholders === []) ? $message : strtr($message, $placeholders);
}

$beforeStr="YOUR NAME {CH_NAME} {URL_NAME}";
$values = ['CH_NAME'=>"John",'URL_NAME'=>"http://xxxx"];

echo replace_placeholder($beforeStr,$values);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use string interpolation. You need to use double-quote delimited strings `"`. Then just prefix your braces with a dollar sign:

```
echo "Hello ${NAME}";
```

The braces don't really do anything for you though, as the following works too:

```
echo "Hello $NAME";
```